# Is $f$ a constant function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)|\in \Bbb Z\forall z\in \Bbb C$.

> Is $f$ a constant function?

I took up $f(z)=e^{iy}$ as an example then $|f(z)|=1\in \Bbb Z$ so the answer is **NO** but the answer is given  to be **YES**.

How should I do it?

Comment: $|e^{iy}|=1$ only for real $y$.  If you mean $f(z)=\exp(i{\rm \ Im\ }z)$ I think that isn't holomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't work. Let $z=-100000 i$. Then $f(z)=e^{100000}$ which has modulus $e^{100000}$

I'll give you a hint for the problem:

Analytic implies continuous. Modulus is continuous.

Comment: Hence the function $g:z\mapsto |f(z)|$ is continuous and $g:\Bbb C \to \Bbb Z$ and continuous image of a connected set is connected so $|f(z)|$ is constant ans so is $f$

Comment: Am I right ;please check

Comment: @Amartya Yup, that sounds right!

Answer (score 1):

An entire function is continuous, and the absolute value mapping is continuous from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb R$ too, which ultimately gets us to $|f(z)| = c$ for some integer $c$. Then $f(z)$ is bounded and entire. By Liouville's theorem, every bounded entire function must be constant.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is entire then so is $f'$.  Suppose $f'$ is not identically zero.  Wherever $f'(z)\ne 0$, a neighborhood of $z$ is mapped to an open set by$f$ (i.e., its image under $f$ is a open set).  Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* 10.30.  No open set in $\mathbb{C}$ can have only moduli in $\mathbb{Z}$.  Conclusion:  $f'$ is identically zero.

Comment: This seems way overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0):

By Liouville's theorem, every bounded entire function must be constant. You have a bound here and it is entire(which is given), therefore, it has to be constant.